# AMP browser support?

Tags: amp-html

Looking at the AMP spec, given the reliance on CSS variables to custom style elements, this means current browser support is narrow. See: [Can I use reference](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)

I'm guessing there is a 'graceful fallback' to non custom styled, since browsers not understanding the CSS variables will just ignore that CSS.

Is there a browser compatibility/support matrix for AMP?

Comment: *"does this mean browser support is currently very narrow"* - The answer is: yes, but I guess you already know that, since you linked to the CanIUse reference. It's unclear to me what your actual question is.

Comment: Yeah, I can see the question isn't clear. I'll update it - but basically, "Where is the supported browser matrix for AMP?"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Browser Support

> In general we support the 2 latest versions of major browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari and Opera. We support desktop, phone, tablet and the web view version of these respective browsers.
>
> Beyond that the core AMP library and builtin elements should aim for very wide browser support and we accept fixes for all browsers with market share greater than 1 percent.
>
> In particular, we try to maintain "it might not be perfect but isn't broken"-support for the Android 4.0 system browser and Chrome 28+ on phones.

from [amp faq](https://amp.dev/support/faq/supported-browsers/)

### But.. CSS Variables?

The use of CSS custom properties (aka CSS Variables) is **polyfilled**:

> AMP HTML components that are more complex and nested … may be styled with an explicitly defined set of CSS Custom Properties. These are propagated to any children elements that are dynamically created by the runtime, to achieve the desired style.

from [spec/amp-html-components.md](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-components.md)

Comment: The description of supported browsers - used in this answer and in the official docs - is kinda' strange: IE11 will obviously be a major browser for a while to come.  I realize that AMP is primarily targetted at mobile, but some sites will want to use it for desktop too and you seem to want to support that.  I hope you will extend your "it might not be perfect but isn't broken" support to IE11.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Paul Irish [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33112348/912946), there is now a dedicated desktop web browser for AMP pages: [**AMP Browser**](http://ampbrowser.com) based on Chromium.