# What happens if an unsupported browser tries to open an AMP page?

Tags: amp-html

I am starting to dig into AMP-HTML capabilities.
I see that the browser support is supposed to be quite large: https://www.ampproject.org/support/faqs/supported-platforms

> "In general we support the 2 latest versions of major browsers like
>   Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari and Opera. We support desktop, phone,
>   tablet and the web view version of these respective browsers.
>
> Beyond that, the core AMP library and built-in elements should aim for
>   very wide browser support and we accept fixes for all browsers with
>   market share greater than 1 percent.
>
> In particular, we try to maintain "it might not be perfect but isn't
>   broken"-support for the Android 4.0 system browser and Chrome 28+ on
>   phones."*

But I wonder anyway: what happens if an unsupported broswer (<1% market share I guess) tries to load an AMP page?
Will the user be shown just a blank page?

Thanks!

Comment: There is also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076515/amp-browser-support)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [github forum](https://github.com/ampproject/amp-by-example/issues/190), it seems that is the case:

> some older browsers (e.g IE9) won't show anything at all